# How to fix 'Non-exhaustive patterns in function' error in haskell?

Tags: haskell, tuples

I am trying to create a function which takes a list of tuples as argument and sort the by the second element. It doesn't print anytning else, just the error '*** Exception: main.hs:20:1-76: Non-exhaustive patterns in function sortWords'
Here is the code:

```
sortWords :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]

sortWords [(str,num)] = sortBy (\x y -> compare (snd x) (snd y)) [(str,num)]`
```

And here is how I call the function

```
main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ sortWords [("friend",1),("she",2)]
```

I have to say that I run my program on http://Repl.it website

Thanks!

Comment: That pattern only matches to lists with only one element.

Comment: So how do I create a pattern to match multiple elements from a list? @DannyuNDos

Comment: @s_diaconu Please create another question, for your new question.

Comment: Enable warnings with `-Wall` and GHC will point out the missing cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sortWords [(str,num)] =
```

Your function definition (above) pattern matches for a list containing a single element which is a tuple with variables for each of the two values.

You seem to want just a variable and not a pattern match at all:

```
sortWords xs  = sortBy (\x y -> compare (snd x) (snd y)) xs
```

or eta reduced:

```
sortWords = sortBy (\x y -> compare (snd x) (snd y))
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Never crossed my mind not to put argument.