# How to create a pattern to match all the elements from a list of tuples?

Tags: haskell, tuples

I am trying to create a function which takes a list of tuples as argument. The function is sorting the list of tuples by the second element from each tuple. The code I have is creating a pattern which is matching a list of tuples with only one element. To test, I am calling the function with a list of tuples with two element and I have 'Non-exhaustive patterns in function' error.

How do I create a pattern to match all the elements from the list of tuples.

Here is the code to create the function.

`sortWords :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]`

`sortWords [(str,num)] = sortBy (\x y -> compare (snd x) (snd y)) [(str,num)]`

And here is how I call the function.

`main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ sortWords [("friend",1),("she",2)]`

I run my program on http://repl.it.

Comment: So... should I copy and paste from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138148/how-to-fix-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-function-error-in-haskell

Comment: I am not sure how is working, but yes if this is the way. Thanks again @ThomasM.DuBuisson

Comment: @SanSolo True, but in OP's defense, on that page they were asked to create another question. (BTW, we probably should have a reference question for "why is `f [x] = ...` failing?` and close all similar questions as a duplicate. This specific question is frequently re-posted on SO, in different forms.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to pattern match anything here. Just give the entire list parameter a name.

```
sortWords pairs = sortBy (\x y -> compare (snd x) (snd y)) pairs
```

This can further be η-reduced:

```
sortWords = sortBy (\x y -> compare (snd x) (snd y))
```

Pattern matching *would* make sense in the inner lambda though:

```
sortWords = sortBy (\(_,x) (_,y) -> compare x y)
```

There are standard helper functions that make it even simpler:

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)

sortWords = sortBy $ comparing snd
```

Comment: Both solutions tested and work good. Thanks.